# Open 'ipython notebook' as: IPython notebook vs Jupyter

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I expected to find more documentation on the following:

> **From one computer: `C:\Python>ipython notebook` opens the browser as *'IPython Notebook'*.**
>
> **From second computer: `C:\Python>ipython notebook` opens the browser as *'Jupyter'*.**

I dont have a preference, but **when saving from the *'Jupyter'* browser, I can no longer open a .ipnb file in the *'IPython Notebook'* browser**.  I encounter a **"bad request"** error.

Initially I assumed that 'ipython notebook' had been updated to use 'Jupyter' as its browser so I updated (`pip install "ipython[notebook]"`) on both computers with no effect.  Clearly I am missing something.

---

**Did `ipython notebook` switch to using *Jupyter*?  If so, am I incorrectly updating IPython?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

ipython Notebook is now called Jupyter so perhaps a different version of Anaconda is installed on the other computer?

So Jupyter is what ipython Notebook will continue to develop as - they dropped python as it is basically "agnostic" now: it can load different languages - python 2 or 3, but also R , Julia and more.

helpful video on Jupyter [intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rc4JQWowG5I)

you can try:

`pip install --upgrade "ipython[all]"`

Comment: For posterity: I don't think this is entirely (*read: semantically*) accurate.  See the answer I've added.

Answer (score 25):

`ipython` is still an active project all its own --- an interactive python program.  `jupyter` is a language-agnostic app that branched **out of** `ipython` (specifically, `ipython notebook`).

The `jupyter notebook` is a generalization of the `ipython` version ---- it is now a web-app that can be used as a notebook for a huge variety of different languages (not just `python`).  The `jupyter notebook` still uses `ipython` as the 'kernel' for running python code.

**As for the practical aspects of your question: for the future, you should use `jupyter` to launch notebooks instead of `ipython`.**  It is now present in all of the standard package managers.

From the ipython homepage:

[Jupyter and the future of IPython](http://ipython.org/#jupyter-and-the-future-of-ipython)

> IPython is a growing project, with increasingly language-agnostic
>   components. IPython 3.x was the last monolithic release of IPython,
>   containing the notebook server, qtconsole, etc. As of IPython 4.0, the
>   language-agnostic parts of the project: the notebook format, message
>   protocol, qtconsole, notebook web application, etc. have moved to new
>   projects under the name Jupyter. IPython itself is focused on
>   interactive Python, part of which is providing a Python kernel for
>   Jupyter.